# Get access to a blocked popup

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, popup

Using javascript I want to open a popup with
var mypopup = window.open(...)

Using firefox, if the popup blocker is on and blocked the popup, then if the user clicks on "show the popup" to get it anyway, then the popup is open but my variable mypopup is still empty.

Is there any way to get access to the popup again ?

Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button which will open the function.

```
<buttononClick="myFunc()">Button</button>
```